# Firebase Auth email already use with account linking enabled

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase, apple-sign-in

Here is my issue.

- I want to allow my users to sign in in my app using different providers (Apple & Google)
- If the email is the same, they should link to the SAME user

My issue is that I have enabled the setting on Firebase Console.

> Authentication > Settings > User Account Linking > Link accounts that use the same email

I created my user initially with Google. Now, I logged out and I'm trying to log back in using Apple but it fails saying:

> "code": "auth/email-already-in-use", "credentials": null, "userInfo": {"authCredential": null, "code": "email-already-in-use", "message": "The email address is already in use by another account."}

This is the code I'm calling after Apple successfully creates the credential.

```
  const createUserWithCredentials = async (
    credential: FirebaseAuthTypes.AuthCredential,
  ) => {
    try {
      const currentUser = auth().currentUser;
      let res: FirebaseAuthTypes.UserCredential;
      if (currentUser) {
        console.log('Attempt to link with anonymous user..');
        res = await currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
      } else {
        console.log('Attempt to sign up a brand new account..');
        res = await auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
      }
      return res;
    } catch (error) {
      const freshCredentials = error.userInfo.authCredential;
      console.log({ code: error.code });
      if (
        error.code === 'auth/provider-already-linked' ||
        error.code == 'auth/credential-already-in-use' ||
        error.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use'
      ) {
        console.log('User already exists so linking the accounts');
        await auth().signInWithCredential(freshCredentials);
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  };
```

My console output shows this:

```
 LOG  Attempt to link with anonymous user..
 LOG  {"code": "auth/email-already-in-use", ... }
 LOG  User already exists so linking the accounts
 INFO TypeError: Cannot read property 'providerId' of undefined
```

This tells me that my call to `linkWithCredential()` fails. Then as a fallback we call `signWithCredential` which should work. The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors) says that the error `FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse` is only thrown when "one account per email address" is enabled. I'm not sure what this means.